# How i can prove that $x^2=x\cos(x)+\sin(x)$ has 2 real roots?

Tags: limits, derivatives, trigonometry

How i can prove that $x^2=x\cos(x)+\sin(x)$ has 2 real roots?

I have tried to solve this by studying $f(x)'$ and $f''(x)$, and lateral limits $\lim f(x)$ when $x$ tends to $+$ and $-$ $\infty$.

Studying the first derivate has a minimum value when $x=0$ and $f(0)=1$. As the second derivate is $>0$ that minimum value is relative 'local'.

When the limit tends to + infinity = $+\infty$  and when the limit tends to - infinity = $-\infty$

I do not know what to conclude. Can anyone help me to resolve this problem, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $x = 0$ is a real root (just plug $0$ into both sides). As $x \rightarrow +\infty$, then $f(x) = x^2 - x\cos(x) - \sin(x)$ is positive. However $f'(0) < 0$ and so there is a neighborhood $(0,y)$ where $f(x)$ is negative. But since it is eventually positive by the intermediate value theorem it must've hit $0$ somewhere in between.

[image: here]

Comment: And why when I graph the function I see two different roots that are distinct from 0? [function graph by Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%3Dxsen%28x%29%2Bcos%28x%29)

Comment: Because that's $x^2 = x\sin(x) + \cos(x)$ which not what you originally asked for.

Comment: Ok you are right, thanks

Comment: You wont see roots distinct from zero, the equation has two roots including zero!

Comment: @Bhauyal Simply graphing it shows a real root around $1.173$, not sure why you think it has no other real root.